# React does not render children when the parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Please take a look at this code https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-waterfall-9b2hd.

Why the children component is not rendered when the parent state changes.

If i use `<Child parentProxy={proxy} />` in the Parent instead of children it works fine.(without key)

What am i doing wrong. i know i can set the key of fragment to value and it will trigger the render of 'children'.

i am trying to understand why it is not rendering when i use 'children' without fragment key.

Thanks

Problem Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class parentProxy {
  constructor() {
    this.setValue = () => void 0;
    this.getValue = () => 1;
  }
  public setValue: (value: number) => void;
  public getValue: () => number;
}

interface childProps {
  parentProxy: parentProxy;
}

interface parentProps {
  proxy: parentProxy;
}

export const Child: React.FunctionComponent<childProps> = ({ parentProxy }) => {
  const onClick = (): void => {
    parentProxy.setValue(parentProxy.getValue() + 1);
  };

  return <span onClick={onClick}>{"Click Me" + parentProxy.getValue()}</span>;
};

export const Parent: React.FunctionComponent<parentProps> = ({
  proxy,
  children
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);

  const getValue = (): number => value;

  proxy.getValue = getValue;
  proxy.setValue = setValue;

  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};

export const App = () => {
  const proxy = new parentProxy();
  return (
    <Parent proxy={proxy}>
      <Child parentProxy={proxy} />
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code here. [Something in my website doesn’t work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: agreed. I edited the post and added the code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating props directly which is an anti pattern. Rather, use `useState` to create a `proxy` and `setProxy`. then, use `setProxy` on a `useEffect` at Parent component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

class parentProxy {
  constructor() {
    this.setValue = () => void 0;
    this.getValue = () => 1;
  }
  public setValue: (value: number) => void;
  public getValue: () => number;
}

interface childProps {
  parentProxy: parentProxy;
}

interface parentProps {
  setProxy: Dispatch<SetStateAction<parentProxy>>;
}

export const Child: React.FunctionComponent<childProps> = ({ parentProxy }) => {
  const onClick = (): void => {
    parentProxy.setValue(parentProxy.getValue() + 1);
  };

  return <span onClick={onClick}>{"Click Me" + parentProxy.getValue()}</span>;
};

export const Parent: React.FunctionComponent<parentProps> = ({
  setProxy,
  children
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);

  const getValue = React.useCallback((): number => value, [value]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setProxy((proxy: parentProxy) => ({ ...proxy, getValue, setValue }))
  }, [getValue, setValue, setProxy])
  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};

export const App = () => {
  const [proxy, setProxy] = React.useState(new parentProxy());
  return (
    <Parent setProxy={setProxy} >
      <Child parentProxy={proxy} />
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you i understand now. It is an anti pattern. We will try to change it in our projects.